# VLAN Testing 3com switch

Tags: networking, network-monitoring, 3com

Hi there I am currently setting up a couple of vlan in work. Hoping that this is going to help with network traffic.

The one question that I have is how do I test the vlan  when I have finished to ensure that they are working correctly.

This is being done on 3com switches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try to perform a ping test from a computer in vlan A to a computer in vlan B. 
normally computers in seperate VLAN's can not communicate unless there is a router present that does routing between the VLANS.

In this case a traceroute should show the router.

Comment: I have 3 vlans vlan1 the management vlan2 and vlan 3

vlan1 cant ping vlan 2 and vice versa

should a computer on vlan1 the management vlan be able to ping both?

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you can do to test is to populate the VLANs with computers, then do tcpdump/wireshark/snoop operations on random computers to make sure they are not seeing broadcast traffic from the other VLANs.